# How can I preserve double spacing when users paste text into Quill.js editor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quill

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, which uses Quill.js. I want users to be able to copy double spaced text from, say, MS Word, and paste it into my Quill editor while preserving their double spacing.

In View:

```
    <div class="editor">
        @Html.Raw(Model.EvaluationText)
    </div>
```

js:

```
    var basicEditor = new Quill('.editor', {
        modules: {
            toolbar: {
                container: '.editor-toolbar'
            }
        },
        theme: 'snow'
    });
```

When I look at devtools, I see that there is a div with class 'ql-paste-manager,' which is what I think I need to override, but I'm not sure how or if this is the way to go.

Comment: What's the point? Double spacing will be ignored when you render it as HTML, anyways. The only way to maintain double-spacing would be to wrap the whole shebang in `<pre></pre>` tags, but doesn't work well for long form text on the web.

Comment: The point is to show text copied into the editor in double-spacing. I see what you're saying about the pre element...but are you saying that the endeavor is altogether impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the text is double spaced you can control this with CSS. Just set the line height to 200% (or whatever value you'd like). Ex.

```
.ql-editor div, .ql-editor li {
  line-height: 200%;
}
```

However Quill's paste manager does not currently support detecting if the text pasted was single or double spaced.

Comment: I have not tested it, but I think this approach is the simplest (though I'm not a huge fan of using css for this).